# Open sets with compact closure containing a given compact set

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $K \subset X$ be a compact subspace, and $U \subset X$ an open set, such that $K \subset U$.

> Can we find an open set $V \subset X$ such that $K \subset V \subset U$ and $\overline V$ is compact?

I know that for all $x \in U$ there is an open set $V_x \ni x$ with compact closure contained in $U$. But the closure of $\bigcup_{x \in K} V_x$ doesn't have to be compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $\cup_{x\in K} V_x$ that you mention is almost what we want.  Since $K$ is compact and $\{V_x\}_{x\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, we can choose a finite subcover.  That is, we can choose $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in K$ so that
\begin{equation}
V = \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}
\end{equation}
covers $K$.  But we can also check that
\begin{equation}
\overline{V} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{V}_{x_i}
\end{equation}
is compact (and contained in $U$).

Comment: Yes, I see. In the last part you used something like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168592/closure-of-finite-unions or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812231/closure-of-union-of-two-sets. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, both of those links seem to include what you need to show on the last step here. No problem!