# Closure of the union = Union of closures

Tags: general-topology

I have seen that $\text{cl}(A\cup B)=\text{cl}(A)\cup \text{cl}(B)$. However I don't see why this is true. I can see the the right to left inclusion, but I can't see the inclusion from left to right. Say that I have an element $x$  contained only in two open sets one that intersects $A\cup B$ only in $A\setminus B$ and and another that intersects only in $B\setminus A$ isn't this a contradiction?

Edit: I have seen the proof but I still can't understand what is wrong with the counterexaple above

Thanks in advance

Comment: Choose some limit point of LHS and observe that it belong to the RHS.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(1) ($\supset$) **::**
\begin{align*}
A \subset A \cup B \implies \text{cl}(A) \subset \text{cl}(A \cup B)
\\B \subset A \cup B \implies \text{cl}(B) \subset \text{cl}(A \cup B)
\end{align*}
therefore yielding that $\text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B) \subset\text{cl}(A \cup B)$

(2) ($\subset$) **::**

The subset $\text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B)$ is closed and contains both $A$ and $B$, therefore $A \cup B \subset \text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B)$. $\text{cl}(A \cup B)$ is defined to be smallest closed set which contains $A \cup B$, so that any closed set which contains $A\cup B$ also contains $\text{cl}(A \cup B)$. Therefore $\text{cl}(A \cup B) \subset \text{cl}(A) \cup \text{cl}(B)$.

Comment: But how come $x$ \in cl(A)? I have a neigbourhood of $x$ only intersecting at B\A so this neigbourhood does not intersect A so it shouldn't be a limitpoint of A right?

Comment: @TheGeometer Indeed, I've got confused! Define your two open sets to be $U_1$ and $U_2$. Then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a third open set containing $x$, that neither intersect $A$ or $B$. So $x \not\in \text{cl}(A \cup B)$ ;). So it's not a counterexample.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks man I got so paranoid with that problem:P

Comment: Is the proof for the first part valid for an arbitrary collection of sets?

Comment: @H.R.  No, consider $\{x \in (0,1)\}$.  Then, $(0,1)=\cup_{x} cl\{x\} \subseteq cl(\cup_x \{x\})=[0,1]$.  If you post as a separate question; I will poste this as an answer :)

Answer (score 12):

In your proposed counterexample, you've forgotten that open sets are closed under finite intersection.

So if $x$ has a neighborhood that only meets $A\cup B$ in $B\setminus A$ and a neighborhood that only meets $A\cup B$ in $A\setminus B$, then the intersection of these neighborhoods doesn't meet $A\cup B$ at all.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use the following definition of closure:

> Let $A$ be a subset of $(X,\tau)$. Then the set $A \cup A'$, consisting of the set $A$ and all it's limit points it's called the closure of $A$ and is denoted by $\overline A$.

So, we want to prove that $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} = \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$.

#### Part 1

Let's start by proving that $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \subseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$.

Let $x \in  \overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)}$, Then we have that $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup (A_1 \cup A_2)'$ (this is the definition of closure).

If $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)$, then, because $\overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2 = (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup (A_1' \cup A_2') $, we have that $x \in \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$.

If $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)'$, then we have that $x$ is a limit point of the set $A_1 \cup A_2$. By the definition of limit point this means that, for every open set $B \in \tau$ such that $x \in B$, $\exists p \in (A_1 \cup A_2): p \in B$ and $p \neq x$. because $p \in A_1 \cup A_2$ we have that $(p \in A_1) \vee (p \in A_2)$ whitch is the same as saying that $x$ is a limit point of $A_1$ $\vee$ $x$ is a limit point of $A_2$. Thus $x \in (A_1' \cup A_2') \to x \in \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$.

This means that  $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \subseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$.

#### Part 2

Now let's prove that $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \supseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$

Let $x \in \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$. Then $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup (A_1' \cup A_2')$.

If $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)$, it's trivial that $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup (A_1 \cup A_2)' = \overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)}$

If $x \in (A_1' \cup A_2')$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A_1$ or a limit point of $A_2$. This tells us that, for every $B \in \tau$ such that $x \in B$, $\exists p \in A_1 \vee \exists k \in A_2: p \in B \vee k \in B$, such that both $p$ and $k$ are different from $x$. But $p \in A_1 \subseteq A_1 \cup A_2$, and $k \in A_2 \subseteq A_1 \cup A_2$. So we have that $p,k \in A_1 \cup A_2$. So $x$ is also a limit point of $A_1 \cup A_2 \to x \in \overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)}$. This implies that: $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \supseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$

#### Part 1 + Part 2 (Conclusion)

From part 1 we deduced that $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \subseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$, and from part 2 $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} \supseteq \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$. This leads us to the conclution that $\overline{(A_1 \cup A_2)} = \overline A_1 \cup \overline A_2$

Comment: Wonderful answer! Maybe I humbly suggest though, it is good practice to use brackets when writing logic propositions. E.g. writing $(p \in A_1) \lor (p \in A_2)$ will be clearer than writing $p \in A_1 \lor p \in A_2$

Comment: You are absolutely right. I wrote this answer before I started studying math in college, and now, after some years, I totally agree with you. @Newton

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in Cl(A\cup B)$ then every open set containing $x$ intersects $A\cup B$.  Thus for $x \in U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X$.  If $U_\alpha$ intersects $A$, then $x \in Cl(A)$ else $x \in Cl(B)$ either way $x \in Cl(A)\cup Cl(B)$.

Comment: This is because if $y\in Cl(A)$ iff every open set containing $y$ intersects $A$.

Comment: I think I have a confusion with the definition. How I know it is that $x$ is a limit point of a subset $S$ of a topological space if every neigbourhood of $x$ intersects with $S$. So in our case if $x$ has a neigbourhood only intersecting $A\B$ and another only intersecting $B\A$ it should be a limit point only of $A\cupB$ and not of A or B.Am I using wrond definition or saying something wrong?

Comment: The $Cl(A)$ is the limit points unioned with the set A.  So $Cl(A)=A \cup A'$.  I believe this is the confusion, though I am slightly confused on what your counterexample is saying.

Answer (score 2):

We have to proof that $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

$(\subset)$

\begin{align}
x \notin \overline{A \cup B} &  \iff \exists V_x (\text{neighborhood of x})  : V_x \cap (A \cup B) = \varnothing\\
&\iff(V_x \cap A) \cup (V_x \cap B) = \varnothing\\
&\implies V_x \cap A= \varnothing \text{ and }  V_x \cap B = \varnothing\\
&\iff x \notin \overline{A} \text{ and } x \notin \overline{A}\\
&\iff x \notin \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}
\end{align}

$(\supset)$
\begin{align}
x \in \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}  & \iff x \in \overline{A} \text{ or } x \in \overline{B}\\
&\iff \forall V_x : V_x \cap A \ne \varnothing \text{ or } V_x \cap B \ne \varnothing\\ 
&\implies (V_x \cap A) \cup (V_x \cap B) \ne  \varnothing\\
&\iff V_x \cap (A \cup B) \neq \varnothing\\
&\iff x \in \overline{A \cup B}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Infinite point sequence from  (A ∪ B) contains an infinite subsequence from A or contains an infinite subsequence from B

Comment: ok but what is wrong wit my counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck at the same point. I was able to use contraposition to make things easier - I believe this works:

We want to show that $x\in (H\cup K)' \Rightarrow x \in H' \cup K'$ (and thus $x\in \overline{H} \cup \overline{K}$ )

By way of contraposition, suppose $x \notin H' \cup K'$

Thus there exists an open $D$ containing $x$ which contains no points of either $H$ or of $K$ distinct from $x$. In other words, $D$ contains no points of $H\cup K$ distinct from $x$.

Thus $x \notin(H\cup K)'$

Answer (score 1):

This is just for fun. The “abstract nonsense” can be converted into a more concrete proof.

---

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathscr{P}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Fix a topological space $X$ and let $\P(X),\C(X)$ be viewed as posetal categories where $\P$ denotes power set and $\C$ denotes the collection of all closed sets.

Then there is a forgetful $\iota:\C(X)\hookrightarrow\P(X)$ and the closure operator $\cl:\P(X)\to\C(X)$ is its left adjoint. That is, $\cl$ is the *reflector* for the *reflective subcategory* $\C(X)\subseteq\P(X)$.

In $\P(X)$, (finite) unions are viewable as colimits (namely, a union will be the coproduct of the unionands) and in $\C(X)$ we have that colimits of *finite* diagrams are also given by the union operation.

Then by the theorem: “left adjoints are cocontinuous”, and the observation that isomorphism is equality in these categories: $$\cl\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j\right)=\bigcup_{j=1}^n\cl(A_j)$$

Follows for all $A_1,\cdots,A_j\in\P(X)$.

The same proof, indeed the *dual* proof, shows that the interior of a finite intersection is the finite intersection of the interiors.